# Polymer paper-ripple disable/enable animation dynamically

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

With Polymer 1.1...

using `<paper-ripple fit><paper-ripple>` how can I enable/disable the animation dynamically?

```
 <template>
    <section class="relative enabledHover"
      onclick="page('/portfolio')"
      on-click="changePaperHeaderPanel">
      <paper-ripple fit hidden="{{!enabled}}"></paper-ripple>
      <div class="vertical layout">
```

Comment: Can you use `hidden` to hide it?

Comment: Naw, tried that also to no success

Comment: What exactly is not working when using hidden?

Comment: If I do a click on the parent element `paper-ripple` is a child of, the ripple animation still happens even with `hidden` on `paper-ripple`.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: It should be `hidden$="{{!enabled}}"`.

Comment: That did it.... thanks!